# Retrieve value from NSDictionnary

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a NSDictionary and I don't know how I can retrieve the value of "@mode" and "@route" (this is from a json response).

How I can do that?

Thanks!

This is the NSDictionary :

```
{
"@mode" = WALK;
"@route" = "Rue University";
distance = "17.513516908661757";
duration = 13000;
endTime = "2011-04-29T12:08:59.395-04:00";
from =     {
    geometry = "{\"type\": \"Point\", \"coordinates\": [-73.57120386807037,45.503820214186405]}";
    lat = "45.503820214186405";
    lon = "-73.57120386807037";
    name = "Rue University";
};
legGeometry =     {
    length = 3;
    points = "{mvtG`k``MOd@ME";
};
startTime = "2011-04-29T12:08:46.395-04:00";
steps =     {
    walkSteps =         (
                    {
            absoluteDirection = NORTHWEST;
            becomes = false;
            distance = "17.513516908661757";
            elevation = "";
            lat = "45.503820214186405";
            lon = "-73.57120386807037";
            stayOn = false;
            streetName = "Rue University";
        },
                    {
            absoluteDirection = NORTH;
            becomes = true;
            distance = "0.0";
            elevation = "";
            lat = "45.50390573910769";
            lon = "-73.57139257694809";
            relativeDirection = RIGHT;
            stayOn = false;
            streetName = "street transit link";
        }
    );
};
to =     {
    geometry = "{\"type\": \"Point\", \"coordinates\": [-73.571363,45.503971]}";
    lat = "45.503971";
    lon = "-73.571363";
    name = "Station McGill";
    stopId = 32;
};
```

Comment: That looks more like a dictionary than an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like object at index 0 is a NSDictionary.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *route = [dict objectForKey:@"@route"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[myDictionary objectForKey:@"@mode"];
```

Comment: Added a '@' before "@mode" to make it @"@mode". The key needs to be an object, so you should use a constant NSString here instead of a C string.

Answer (score 0):

Given an `NSDictionary dict`, you can retrieve the value corresponding to the key `@mode` using:

```
[dict objectForKey:@"@mode"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:
1) The NSMutableArray is an array of JSON formatted strings.
2) The  NSMutableArray is an array of NSDictionaries.

If its #1, then you need to use the Cocoa JSON stuff to decode the JSON string into an NSDictionary:

```
 NSDictionary* aDict = [[myArray objectAtIndex:0] JSONValue];
```

OR

```
 NSDictionary* aDict = [theArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

The JSON stuff is available here http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

Then this should work:

```
 NSString* theMode = [aDict objectForKey:@"@mode"];
 NSLog(@"the mode is %@, as read from the dictionary %@", theMode, aDict);
```

--Tom